# While in C (with log Not)

Tags: c, while-loop

can you please help me to understand this while loop:

```
while (!(a % b))        
  {
   a = a / b;               
   higher = b; 
  }
```

I dont get the point with the (!(a % b)

Comment: `%` is the modulus (remainder) operator.

Comment: Me neither, since your code snippet has no context,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a % b` returns the remainder of `a` divided by `b` (e.g. 5 % 2 returns 1, 4 % 2 returns 0)
Integers are converted to true if not equal to 0
--> (!(a % b)) is true while `a` is not a multiple of `b`.

Answer (score 3):

`while (!(a % b))` is equivalent to

```
while ((a % b) == 0)
```

Which means *if `a` is a multiple of `b` then execute the body else come out of the loop*.